# Compiling Python into a windows application

Tags: python, windows, exe, kivy

Currently I am working on a fork of someone else's project, that is written in the Python programming language.

I have access to all the source code I need, with all the changes I wanted to make, and everything 'set' to how I need it.

My current step is trying to somehow compile it, so it runs as windows in a stand-alone application. I know this is possible because this is how the source-application runs. Currently I have access to Visual Studio with the python extension module, WinPython, the kivy framework itself that the GUI was built with, etc.

But I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. My cursory research has suggested a program called py2exe but that does not work with what I need, based on what I can tell.

Comment: so is it a kivy application? if so http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

copied from http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html

**Create the spec file**

For this example, we’ll package the touchtracer example and embed a custom icon. The touchtracer example is the kivy\examples\demo\touchtracer directory and the main file is named main.py.

Double click on the `Kivy.bat` and a console will open.

Go to the pyinstaller 2.1 directory and create the initial spec:

```
cd pyinstaller-2.1
python pyinstaller.py --name touchtracer ..\kivy\examples\demo\touchtracer\main.py
```

You can also add an icon.ico file to the application folder in order to create an icon for the executable. If you don’t have a .ico file available, you can convert your icon.png file to ico using the web app ConvertICO. Save the icon.ico in the touchtracer directory and type:

```
python pyinstaller.py --name touchtracer --icon ..\kivy\examples\demo\touchtracer\icon.ico ..\kivy\examples\demo\touchtracer\main.py
```

For more options, please consult the PyInstaller 2 Manual.

The spec file will be touchtracer.spec located in inside the pyinstaller + touchtracer directory. Now we need to edit the spec file to add kivy hooks to correctly build the exe. Open the spec file with your favorite editor and add theses lines at the beginning of the spec:

```
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import install_hooks
install_hooks(globals())
```

In the `Analysis()` function, remove the `hookspath=None` parameter. If you don’t do this, the kivy package hook will not be used at all.

Then you need to change the `COLLECT()` call to add the data for touchtracer (touchtracer.kv, particle.png, ...). Change the line to add a Tree() object. This Tree will search and add every file found in the touchtracer directory to your final package:

```
coll = COLLECT( exe, Tree('../kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer/'),
               a.binaries,
               #...
               )
```

We are done. Your spec is ready to be executed!

**Build the spec**

Double click on `Kivy.bat`

Go to the pyinstaller directory, and build the spec:

```
cd pyinstaller-2.1
python pyinstaller.py touchtracer\touchtracer.spec
```

The package will be in the touchtracer\dist\touchtracer directory.

Comment: I learned in the Kivy IRC channel just now that since I used Christph Golke's pre-compiled Windows binary, it does not come with a `Kivy.bat`, which is platform-specific.  Instead, I need to just start a command shell normally.

Comment: ok... I guess ... usually kivy comes as a zip that bundles python and everything else